# Dummy Predictors / Continuous Dependent Variable

Tags: predictive-modeling, prediction, dummy-variables

I have a dataset with 50+ dummy coded variables that represent the purchases of an individual customer. Columns represent the products and the cell values 0 or 1, whether the product has been purchased in the past by this customer (rows = customers) or not. Now, I want to predict how these purchases predict the loyalty of the customer (continuous variable in years). I am struggling to find an appropriate prediction model. What would you suggest for such a prediction problem?

Thank you in advance for all suggestions & hints

Best,
GL

Comment: Have you tried starting simple by using something like a linear regression?

Comment: What did you try so far?